# GPUImage individual Camera logic

Tags: objective-c, gpuimage, core-image, cifilter, ciimage

My app has really many camera logical functions.

I have used CoreImage filters in AVCaptureOutput and show the CIImage in a GLKView until now.

Now I want to blend the CIImage  with a CIFilter over it. But in the "AVCaptureOutput-Loop" the CoreImage filter chain never ends.

So I want to use GPUImage to replace the CoreImage functions.

Is there any way without GPUImageVideoCamera or GPUImageStillCamera, so that I have my own AVCaptureOutput, and can for example:

```
CMSampleBufferRef or CVPixelBufferRef > GPUImage > filter and store the image for the next AVCaptureOutput call > Display in my GLKView
```

Thanks

PS: Sorry for my bad english ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can still use a GPUImageVideoCamera or GPUImageStillCamera for what you describe. A GPUImageBuffer will cache the processed image from one pass through the filter chain (up to the buffer) and will delay its release by one frame. I use this for low-pass filtering, among other things.

You can then feed the output of your operation to a GPUImageView or to a texture, where it could be used within a GLKView.

Comment: But what if you only want to use a GPUImage filter selectively on certain frames depending on other logic? So back to OP's question, is there any way to pass a CMSampleBufferRef into a GPUImage filter? My assumption is that converting the buffer to a UIImage and then passing that into the filter is an unnecessary performance hit but maybe I'm wrong?

Comment: Figured it out: Use GPUImageRawDataInput